# Resolve an old controversy

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

> `Look       between              these               five      words`

What is the answer, and what is the controversy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since ``` `` ``` is used to normally denote an inline code in markdown, I guess the controversy  is between the spaces and tabs. They are all spaces matching the regex `/ +/`. Number of spaces in between them is `7,14,15,6` leading to GNOF (an ill-mannered fellow)? GNOF in rot13 is `tabs`

Comment: Yes, that's it! Can you find the hidden (hint: four-word) message though?

Comment: 4 words or 4 characters? Greater New Orleans Foundation?

Comment: Sorry, four characters.

Comment: Ok. So, is my answer above right? I mean in the answer box

Comment: try "decrypting" `GNOF`

Comment: Yes. Did. See the answer